# How can I optimize function calls while setting the string values?

Tags: c++, function, class, c++11, optimization

In the below code snippet, from `ReadFile()` function I am calling `SetParams()` and `Execute()` multiple times. 
Can I optimize each `SetParams()` and `Execute()`  with single call?

```
bool SubscriptionRead::ReadFile()
{
    IVerification* pReader = new FileReader();
    std::wstring oemPathPublicKey(oemFolderPath)
        , oemPathSessionKey(oemFolderPath)
        , oemPathUserChoices(oemFolderPath);
    oemPathPublicKey.append(PUBLIC_KEY_FILE);
    oemPathSessionKey.append(SESSION_KEY_FILE);
    oemPathUserChoices.append(USERCHOICES_FILE);
    pReader->SetParams((wchar_t*)oemPathPublicKey.c_str(), L"file");
    pReader->Execute();
    pReader->SetParams((wchar_t*)oemPathSessionKey.c_str(), L"file");
    pReader->Execute();
    pReader->SetParams((wchar_t*)oemPathUserChoices.c_str(), L"file");
    pReader->Execute();
    return True;
}

void FileReader::SetParams(wchar_t* wszParams, wchar_t* wszParamType)
{
    m_wszParamType = wszParamType;
    m_wszParams = wszParams;
}

bool FileReader::Execute()
{
    if (wcscmp(m_wszParamType, L"registry") == 0)
    {
        function1();
    }
    else
    {
        function2();
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: maybe explain why you think you cannot, because it isnt clear what is the problem

Comment: What hinders you to create another function which does that in a single call?

Comment: Pass the needed parameters directly to `Execute()`, rather than using another function to set them.    If you want to combine multiple calls of `Execute()` into one, change the argument so it either accepts multiple pairs of arguments, or accepts arguments that are arrays.    Also consider using standard library types (like `std::wstring` or, if passing a set of them, `std::vector<std::wstring>`) rather than playing with arrays of `wchar_t`.

Comment: Honestly I think this is fine as it is. Worry if you have loads more to add.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your problem is calling the functions with different paras, in different lines, you can use [`std::ref`](https://de.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref) as follows to iterate through the *initializer_list* of reference wrapper to the objects(i.e. `std::wstring` s), which reduces some typing:

```
#include <functional>        // std::ref
#include <initializer_list>  // std::initializer_list

bool SubscriptionRead::ReadFile()
{
    IVerification* pReader = new FileReader();  
    // .... other code
    for(auto strKey: {std::ref(oemPathPublicKey), std::ref(oemPathSessionKey), std::ref(oemPathSessionKey)})
    {
        pReader->SetParams((wchar_t*)strKey.c_str(), L"file");
        pReader->Execute(); // does it needed to executed for every path? if no: outside the loop!
    }
    return True;
}
```

---

Also note that, in modern C++ you have *[smart pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/book/intro/smart_pointers)*. Therefore use them, whenever appropriate and avoid manual memory allocations.